# Bibliography style in class file

Tags: bibliographies, document-classes

I wonder if it's possible to add all bibliography style file (.bst) to class file (.cls).  I want to make one file with all styles, definitions, etc.

Comment: Now I have .cls file with all definitions of my own class and .bst file with own bibliography style definition. I would like to have only one file (i.e. .cls file) in folder with .tex file which will contain informations about class and bibliography style.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification. Providing a `\bibliographystyle` instruction in a `.cls` file is certainly an ok thing to do.

Comment: although what @Mico says is true, the `\bibliographystyle` command will merely point to a separate `.bst` file.  the `.bst` file is used by a different program -- bibtex -- and it isn't possible to include the detailed instructions in a .cls file.